# Difference and subsequent error between using Pandas Series and Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

When doing some estimations, calculations, and other fun stuff in Python I came across something really weird and upsetting.

I have this thing where I estimate some parameters using ML-estimation, and have previously assumed that everything was peachy and fine. I read csv-data with pandas, and use the subsequent data for the estimation. Therefore, the data has originally been passed down to the ML-estimation function as Pandas Series. Today I wanted to try some matrix-operations on a thing in the calculation for kicks-and-giggles, and converted the input-data to numpy arrays. However, when I ran the code, the estimation results were different. After restoring some of the multiplications, it was still different. Then I changed back to using Pandas series, and it returned to the previously expected result.

This is where I got curious and now turn to you. Is it so that there is a rounding error between float64 Numpy arrays and float64 Pandas Series so different that when doing my calculations, they get so drastically different?

Consider the following code-example containing a sample from my ML-estimator

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

values = [3.41527085753, 3.606855606852, 3.5550625070226231, 3.680327020956565, \
          3.30270511221, 3.704752803295, 3.6307205395804001, 3.200863997609199, \
          2.90599272353, 3.555062501231, 2.8047528032711295, 3.415270760685753, \
          3.50599277872, 3.445622506242, 3.3047528084632258, 3.219431344191376, \
          3.68032756565, 3.451542245654, 3.2244456543387564, 2.999848273256456]

Ps = pd.Series(values, dtype=np.float64)
Narr = np.array(values, dtype=np.float64)

def getLambda(S, delta = 1/255):
    n = len(S) - 1

    Sx  = sum( S[0:-1] )
    Sy  = sum( S[1:] )
    Sxx = sum( S[0:-1]**2 )
    Sxy = sum( S[0:-1]*S[1:] )

    mu  = (Sy*Sxx - Sx*Sxy) / ( n*(Sxx - Sxy) - (Sx**2 - Sx*Sy) )
    lambd =  np.log((Sxy - mu*Sx - mu*Sy + n*mu**2) / (Sxx -2*mu*Sx + n*mu**2) )/ delta
    a = math.exp(-lambd*delta) 
    return mu, a, lambd

print("Numpy Array calculation gives me mu = {}, alpha = {} and Lambda = {}".format(getLambda(Narr)[0], getLambda(Narr)[1], getLambda(Narr)[2]))
print("Pandas Series calculation gives me mu = {}, alpha = {} and Lambda = {}".format(getLambda(Ps)[0], getLambda(Ps)[1], getLambda(Ps)[2]))
```

The values are just some random value picked from my original data in my larger project.

This will, atleast for me, print:

```
>> Numpy Array calculation gives me mu = 3.378432651661709, alpha = 102.09644146650535 and Lambda = -1179.6090571432392
>> Pandas Series calculation gives me mu = 3.3981019891871247, alpha = nan and Lambda = nan
```

The procedure, method, and original data is identical, and it still gets a difference of about `0.019669` already in the calculation of mu, which is for me really weird and upsetting.

If this is due to difference (keep in mind that I explicity stated that it should be float64 in both cases) in rounding between the two methods of handling data its weird as this just makes me question which and why I should use any of them. Otherwise, there has to be a bug in one of them? Or is there a third alternative which explains everything and was something that I did not know of to begin with?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate covariance matrix?

Comment: I can't give a reason why pandas does what it does, but in general I have found it best to avoid using pandas for numeric computations.  `getLambdas(Ps.values)` will behave correctly.

Comment: I think this problem is due to the intrinsic data alignment of Pandas operations.  When you do math operations on two Pandas Series, those operations are automatically aligned on indexes.  So, variable Sxy is return NaN because missing values in S[0:1] for index 19 and missing value for S[1:] at index 0.

Comment: Add `print(Sxy)` to your code.  You'll see  the difference between the numpy result and the Pandas result that Scott points out.

Comment: Yes, I found that as well just now. I was about to write an answer to Scotts comment, but got distracted. So the solution going forward should be to simply avoid Pandas if I intend to do math operations on series/arrays?